# How do I access an external data file from withtin a javascript file in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, d3.js

I have my html in my .jsp file to show a graph that I have made with d3, and in my javascript file which handles the graph I'm using:

```
d3.tsv("data/tweet_example2.tsv", function (data) {
    //code to display the graph
}
```

I have the location of the tsv data file set as "data/tweet_example2.tsv", but I know that's not right as I need to have the data file on the client side for me to access it. So how do I get that tsv file static on the client side to access, and is the "data/tweet_example2.tsv" syntax correct to use? Any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

My folder structure with location of tsv data file:

[image]

Comment: Try "tempData/tweet_example.tsv"

Answer (score 0):

If your tempData folder is part of a static resource, then you could access your file using an url like http://yourhost:8080/context/tempData/tweet_example2.tsv

In this case, then you could call the function like this:

```
d3.tsv("http://yourhost:8080/context/tempData/tweet_example2.tsv", function (error, data) {
    //code to display the graph
});
```

Comment: How do I know if my tempData is part of a static resource?

Comment: You must have a line in your servlet xml config, like <mvc:resources .... Check: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: I have <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> in my servlet config xml but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you sure you could access a js file this way: http://yourhost:8080/context/resources/js/yourjs.js ? because your tsv file also should be accessible http://yourhost:8080/context/resources/tempData/tweet_example2.tsv

Comment: I've solved it now. Instead of using a different js file for the script I added the script code into the jsp and just used:

var src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/tempData/tweet_example2.tsv";

d3.tsv(src, function (error, data) {}. Thanks for taking the time to help me out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just putting my js code into the jsp instead of referencing it in an external file, and in my jsp's html I used:

```
var src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/tempData/tweet_example2.tsv";
d3.tsv(src, function (error, data) {//code for graph}
```

to refer to the tsv file. This done the trick.

My jsp config xml also contained .